# Prevent cross site file uploads onto my server?

Tags: php, linux, apache, iptables

Is there a way to a FILE upload to my site from other websites?

I have a form that takes semi-large video files and authenticates with tokens after the form is submitted on client and serverside. However, since we may have 300 people uploading files at the same time, we do not want some cross site hacker trying to upload files that won't go through regardless.

Issue with them even attempting it is that when the file begins uploading, it takes up our memory resources (right?) and bandwidth.

Solution I'm looking for is have apache or iptables or the php script that the file is being sent to, to not allow the upload as soon as it sees it's not from out website's upload page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be using form tokens to ensure that the form is submitted via your server only. For this create a form token with random values, put it in a session as well as in a hidden form field. When form is posted check this hidden field's value against the session. If form token exist and matches the session allow upload, otherwise not.

**Your upload form page**

**PHP Code :**

```
$token = md5 (uniqid (rand (), true));
$_SESSION[“token”] = $token;
```

**HTML Code :**

```
<form> 
 <input type="file" />
<input type=”hidden” name=”token” value=”<?php echo $token;?>”>
</form>
```

**Your submit page**
 `$_SESSION["token"]` gets overwrited everytime user request your upload page to upload new file. So you don't have to worry about its value being reset.

Comment: I've done that. The issue here though is a person copies his token from a hidden input and bypasses my uploader's max file size, he will end up taking up the server's resources uploading a file that will fail. and if they do that with for example 10 tabs open for upload, it  may crash the server due to resource limit. Maybe my question isn't clear? Or you think that, if this is the case, just let their file fail since they can't possibly upload that many files at the same time.

Comment: I assume there may be evil programs out there that allow for someone to select 100 large files and try to upload them at the same time. That could potentially hurt our resources, right? Or will their connection speed be so slow that it will time them out or the speed of their uploads won't hurt our resources that much.

Comment: how would he do that, suppose i log to your application, the upload form has random value say "asfjh23878afhfjh2834724asfh", this value is in the server session as well. While i submit form before hand the php checks if this hidden field matches the session value. There are two scenario here 1. I change hidden field's value-> as this will not match the session user will not be allowed to upload file. 2nd if from another website i try to post form to upload files -> I will not have valid token to do that. The different form token will be randomly generated each time i refresh the page.

Comment: If you don't want user to upload more than one files simultaneously, that is the different thing here. But using form tokens helps you much. It prevents from CSRF

Comment: You can also restrict user from uploading multiple files. Like when user uploads first file, before uploading create a session variable and set its value to 1. Next time when he tries to upload another file check this session. If value equals 1 then dont allow upload

Comment: Ooooh, I see. Understood now. Keeping form tokens in sessions is also understood, last question then. If i create a form token and put it in a session, lets say $this->session->formtoken = 111, and they open up another tab and go to another upload form and the session gets changed to 222, the first tab won't work anymore, I see this as an inconvenience to the member. Especially if they do it while in the middle of another upload. How would I get around this issue? I don't mind the users doing simultaneous uploads.

Comment: Ive just tested this on my VPS and the point is that you can make a simple form and send a file to any url, even with checks in place and even if its not an upload script and it will consume the servers incoming resources. @Darius choose your host wisely I know with linode uploading is unlimited and not counted towards resources.

Comment: Got it, I'm on my own private colocated server. So for my scenario then, I'll simply use one token, which is generated upon login to make sure it's them and they want to upload. I didn't know that I could send a file to ANY page and it would consume the resources. Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me.

Comment: @Darius, well in the middle of uploading first file if user tries to upload 2nd , you won't face any problem, because first file is already being uploaded, and second tab would have new token in field and session, he will be able to upload 2nd file also. This token will prevent CSRF, i.e. submitting of form via another server, it won't hamper the uploading of multiple file. And do as Lawrence said

Comment: @Darius, use token in upload form not in login form, But its great idea to use form tokens anywhere you use forms.

Comment: So, if I have token 111, i press submit and it connects to upload.php it will remember that the token was 111. While at 50% upload of file 1, I visit another page the session gets changed and click submit for 2nd file, the 1st one will still remember the session was 111, and the 2nd form will know the session is 222?. Rephrased : When I visit form 1, session become 111, I click upload and when it's at 50%, I go to form2 with generated sess of 222, i click upload and that uploads too. Now when server side validating tokens, the session from form 1 submission remains 111 when checking,not 222?

Comment: @Darius, you dont have to worry about that, first you check session if everything good you allow file upload, lets say its uploaded 50%, once uploading is started you don't need the session. Next i open another tab, the form token changes and so do the session, if everything good here, The 2nd file is uploading as well. Again after upload starts we dont need token session. So, you need form tokens and session only before uploading file. Once you have checked session with form field, you allow upload

Comment: Thank you so much for being patient with me. Almost got it down. What happens in the scenario that I visit upload page 1, and upload page 2 in tabs. Sessions get overwritten upon visiting page 2, then I go back to page 1 click submit and page 2 click submit. Where would I check now if token matches the session? This would only allow for page 2 to go through wouldn't it? I think i may have missed something in your explanation. I understand if they get submitted before visiting the form again in another tab, but what if the form gets visited twice before ANY upload happens?

Comment: @Darius, in this scenerio you've to think another solution. Another solution would be allow user uploading multiple files using ajax uploader. I prefer swfuploader http://demo.swfupload.org/. It doesnot make sense user opens 10 different pages to upload files. First they would likely upload first and then go for second.

Comment: And if I use a token that was generated upon login to use throughout the site, that token can get stolen and used? It has to always be random on every page load? Thank you! that was my last question :)

Comment: @Darius if user needs to login to upload files, then you dont need form tokens. You might have saved sessions like username, user id after successful login. Just check if user is logged in before all uploads.